# How to match exact list which is the result of a replication

Tags: python, pattern-matching

if I have a list which is the result of a replication, how do I match it exactly?

```
x = [1, 2] * 10000
match x:
  case list([1, 2] * 10000):
    print(1)
```

gives,

```
    case list([1, 2] * 10000):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the python version?

Comment: python version is 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch cases in python right now doesn't allow simple operations on case conditions.

you can use another class where you define your cases as an alternative :

(for more info check the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html))

```
class Cases:
    A = [1, 2] * 10000
    B = [1, 2] * 100000


x = [1, 2] * 100000

match x:
    case Cases.A:
        print(1)
    case Cases.B:
        print(2)
```

output:

```
2
```